# Room: application crashes on emulator

Tags: android-room

I am adding a second column to my room application. The application builds fine but fails on the emulator.

logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: app.bluecoral.pbtracker, PID: 11773
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:139)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:119)
        androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:452)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:275)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:304)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:54)
        at app.bluecoral.pbtracker.PbDao_Impl$5.call(PbDao_Impl.java:102)
        at app.bluecoral.pbtracker.PbDao_Impl$5.call(PbDao_Impl.java:99)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

PbDao

```
@Dao
interface PbDao {
@Query("SELECT * from pb_table ORDER BY pb, pb_value ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedPbs(): LiveData<List<Pb>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(pb: Pb)

    @Query("DELETE FROM pb_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?